# t Change UIButton Text Based on User Input

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a button on my `UINavigationBar` which I have created using this code:

```
let inputLabel = UIBarButtonItem(title: userInput, style: .plain,   target: self, action: #selector(inputLabelButtonTapped))
```

I want to make the `inputLabel.text` based on what the user inputs. Here is what I imagine the `inputLabelButtonTapped` function to look like, but I cannot code it:

```
inputLabelButtonTapped() {

// Have a keyboard/numberpad appear on the screen
// Save the what the user types on the screen to a newUserInputVariable
// Make the inputLabel.text = newUserInputVariable

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is confusing. You seem to have a `UILabel` named `inputLabel` but you have assigned a `UIBarButtonItem` to `inputLabel`. That won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a mismatch in `UIBarButtonItem` and `UILabel`. The former is a button that can be positioned in a `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`. The latter just displays text.

Instantiate an input field either by adding a `UITextField` or an `UIAlertViewController` to the ViewController:

```
var barButtonItemTitle = String()

// create the alert controller
 let ac = UIAlertController(title:"<SomeName>",
                             message: "<SomeMessage>", 
                             preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
```

Add an `UIAlertAction` to the `UIAlertViewController` with a completion handler that will allow you to update the property for `barButtonItemTitle`

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
//Add a textfield to the alert controller:
 ac.addTextField
```

when you add a `UITextField` to a `UIAlertController` it will appear in an `[TextFields]` if it exists.

```
// Unwrap the textfield array and the first item there and access the text property.
  guard let inputText = ac.textFields?.first?.text else {return}
```

Set the barButtonText property to the text that was pulled out

```
 barButtonText = inputText
}

 // Add action to the controller & present the view.

ac.addAction(action)
present(ac, animated: true)
```

Once the barButtonText is updated with new values, you can use that property to create an instance of `UIBarButtonItem` and place it where ever.

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: barButtonText, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

You can wrap all that into a func that is assigned to your view